# Checkbox style for firefox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have this checkbox system to have an HTML and CSS only togglable dropdown menu, and the system needs to have the checkbox right before the `li` that has a submenu.

I realy dont know how to convert the style to an `::after` or `::before` element with a `<label>` so it works with Firefox, Chrome, Safari and the latests IEs.

I include this link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qEUVd/) for the original design.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have elements between list-items. You need to have then inside the LI. A diagram of what you want would be helpful.

Comment: If you can open this in Chrome, the behavior is working, if I have to move the Checkbox inside the li, I will have to change the css behavior. What is the problem is that in firefox, the checkbox styles don't show as they should, they look like large checkbox. There must be a way, without Javascript to make it look like the one on chrome inside of firefox.

Comment: Firefox does not support styling of checkbox elements. You'll need to use pseudo-elements, possibly combined with opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy, this is my solution; use `<label>` and `::after` elements to set the whole thing. I've fixed it on Fiddle and here's the [result.](http://jsfiddle.net/x3uy6/12/)